# Graphic editor for FIT file editing

Tags: gps, gpx, garmin

I'm searching for a graphic editor to move lon/lat points in FIT file.

Isn't there a software for graphic editing of the lon/lat points recorded in FIT file as can be done easily with GPX files? I searched a lot but couldn't find anything satisfactory. Is there no way to simply change the position of the points by dragging them on a map base (see attached image)? I found a conversation where someone suggested that it couldn't be done because the number of heartbeat recordings (present in the .FIT file) did not correspond to the number of GPS recordings... Exporting my .FIT file in CSV format I realized that it's not like that at all and the file I get is exactly identical to a GPX exported in CSV with the "heartbeat" column added.

Could anyone help me? thank you!

P.S.: there is maybe a solution based on txc file use?

[image]

[image]

Comment: your question seems a bit off topic for this site, maybe try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.  the FIT file format seems proprietary to Garmin and I've only used tools to grab data out of it (e.g. https://github.com/polyvertex/fitdecode) and process it from there in a more open format.  https://developer.garmin.com/fit/overview/ looks like it has code from Garmin if you're happy using that.  you could going FIT -> CSV -> GPX -> modified GPX -> merge CSV files -> modified FIT